# Python get data from IPFS error HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url

Tags: python, ipfs

I try to get data from IPFS by using [ipfs-api](https://pypi.org/project/ipfs-api/). I upload file to IPFS and get CID to put in the code like this.

```
import ipfsApi

api = ipfsApi.Client('127.0.0.1', 5001)

print(api)

api.cat('QmbFMke1KXqnYyBBWxB74N4c5SBnJMVAiMNRcGu6x1AwQH')
```

It's show error like this.

```
HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/cat?stream-channels=true&encoding=json&arg=QmbFMke1KXqnYyBBWxB74N4c5SBnJMVAiMNRcGu6x1AwQH
```

How to fix it?

Comment: it seems like you have to add a text first like `res = client.add('test.txt')` and then cat on that hash from `res` object `client.cat(res['Hash'])`

Comment: @AhmadAnis I add already it show 'Hash': 'QmbFMke1KXqnYyBBWxB74N4c5SBnJMVAiMNRcGu6x1AwQH' when I put hash in api.cat() it show same error

Comment: Can you use `ipfshttpclient`? Or do you have to use `ipfsApi`

Comment: ipfshttpclient.exceptions.VersionMismatch: Unsupported daemon version '0.17.0' (not in range: 0.4.23 ≤ … < 0.8.0)

Comment: https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/py-ipfs-http-client/pull/294

Answer (score 0):

The ipfsapi PIP package and Python module have both been renamed to ipfshttpclient.
See the link :
https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/py-ipfs-http-client#install